# PHP script to get all article IDs joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I developed a script which give me the text of a Joomla article from its ID, something like this:

```
$article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load($address = JRequest::getVar('articleID'));
echo $article->get("introtext");
echo $article->get("fulltext");
```

Now I need a similar script to get ALL (active) article IDs of the current site (maybe ordered from the last to the first like on the joomla homepage).

I gave a look around but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content";
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query); 
$articles = $db->loadObjectList(); 
foreach($articles as $article){
    echo 'ID:' . $article->id . ' Title: ' . $article->title;
}
```

If you want to get all the ID's of articles from a specific category, you could use the following:

```
$catId = 59;
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "'";
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query); 
$articles = $db->loadObjectList(); 
foreach($articles as $article){
    echo 'ID:' . $article->id . ' Title: ' . $article->title;
}
```

Obviously you change `59` to whatever suits your needs

**Note that this method of a database query is for Joomla 1.5**

Hope this helps